# Spring Batch: How to handle processes like nested JSON objects that return more items than they take in?

Tags: spring-batch, java-17

What is the proper way to handle batch processes that return more items than they take in?

I've been up and down the internet about this and cannot find a clear explanation. I'm a novice, but from what I understand Spring Batch processes data in chunks and should take in a return the same object. Immediately a problem comes up. What about nested JSON objects? The answer, flatten the JSON. But, you still need a JSON ItemReader to get the data in, which puts us back at the exact same problem because once the JSON is flattened, it will result in more items than were taken in.

I'm currently solving this with a complicated FlatFileItemWriterBuilder, but I want to know what a better solution is.

## BatchConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Job importLApresets(JobRepository jobRepository, Step flattenJsonStep) {
        return new JobBuilder("importLApresets", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(flattenJsonStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step flattenJsonStep(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                                FlatFileItemWriter<List<TableSectionFlattened>> csvWriter) {
        return new StepBuilder("flattenJsonStep", jobRepository)
                .<TableSections, List<TableSectionFlattened>>chunk(1, transactionManager)
                .reader(readUnflattenedJson())
                .processor(flattenJson())
                .writer(csvWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonItemReader<TableSections> readUnflattenedJson() {
        return new JsonItemReaderBuilder<TableSections>()
                .name("readUnflattenedJson")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("jsonInput.json"))
                .jsonObjectReader(new JacksonJsonObjectReader<>(TableSections.class))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonFlattenerItemProcessor flattenJson() {
        return new JsonFlattenerItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<List<TableSectionFlattened>> csvWriter() {
        return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<List<TableSectionFlattened>>()
                .name("csvItemWriter")
                .resource(new FileSystemResource("jsonOutput.csv"))
                .lineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<List<TableSectionFlattened>>() {
                    {
                        setDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        setFieldExtractor(new FieldExtractor<List<TableSectionFlattened>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Object[] extract(List<TableSectionFlattened> list) {
                                List<String> flattenedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
                                for (TableSectionFlattened flattened : list) {
                                    flattenedStrings.add(
                                            "\"" + flattened.getPreset() + "\","
                                                    + "\"" + flattened.getDsp() + "\","
                                                    + "\"" + flattened.getSource1() + "\","
                                                    + "\"" + flattened.getSource2() + "\","
                                                    + "\"" + flattened.getSource3() + "\""
                                    );
                                }
                                return flattenedStrings.toArray();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }
```

## JsonFlattenerItemProcessor

```
@Log4j2
public class JsonFlattenerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<TableSections, List<TableSectionFlattened>> {
    @Override
    public List<TableSectionFlattened> process(TableSections tableSection) throws Exception {
        List<TableSectionFlattened> tableSectionFlattenedList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (TableRowSections tableRowSection : tableSection.getTableRowSections()) {
            log.info("Processing: " + tableRowSection);
            TableSectionFlattened tableSectionFlattened = TableSectionFlattened.builder()
                    .preset(tableSection.getTableHeader().getValue())
                    .dsp(tableRowSection.getPresets().getValue())
                    .source1(tableRowSection.getColumn2() != null ? tableRowSection.getColumn2().getValue() : null)
                    .source2(tableRowSection.getColumn3() != null ? tableRowSection.getColumn3().getValue() : null)
                    .source3(tableRowSection.getColumn4() != null ? tableRowSection.getColumn4().getValue() : null)
                    .build();
            tableSectionFlattenedList.add(tableSectionFlattened);
        }

        return tableSectionFlattenedList;
    }
}
```

## Sample JSON input

```
[
  {
    "table_header": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "K1 + K1-SB"
    },
    "table_row_sections": [
      {
        "presets": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[K1] + [K1SB_X]"
        },
        "column_2": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1 = O ms +"
        },
        "column_3": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1-SB = O ms +"
        },
        "column_4": null
      },
      {
        "presets": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[K1]+[[K1SB_60]"
        },
        "column_2": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1 = 6 ms +"
        },
        "column_3": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1-SB = O ms +"
        },
        "column_4": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "table_header": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "K1 + SB28"
    },
    "table_row_sections": [
      {
        "presets": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[K1] + [SB28_60]"
        },
        "column_2": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1 = 0.5 ms +"
        },
        "column_3": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "SB28 = 0 ms"
        },
        "column_4": null
      },
      {
        "presets": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[K1] + [SB28_60_C]"
        },
        "column_2": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1 = 6 ms +"
        },
        "column_3": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "SB28 = 0 ms"
        },
        "column_4": null
      },
      {
        "presets": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "[K1] + [SB28_60_Cx]"
        },
        "column_2": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "K1 = 4 ms +"
        },
        "column_3": {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "SB28 = 0 ms"
        },
        "column_4": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## CSV output

Although this is usable. I would rather have the JSON output.

```
"K1 + K1-SB","[K1] + [K1SB_X]","K1 = O ms +","K1-SB = O ms +","null"
"K1 + K1-SB","[K1]+[[K1SB_60]","K1 = 6 ms +","K1-SB = O ms +","null"
"K1 + SB28","[K1] + [SB28_60]","K1 = 0.5 ms +","SB28 = 0 ms","null"
"K1 + SB28","[K1] + [SB28_60_C]","K1 = 6 ms +","SB28 = 0 ms","null"
"K1 + SB28","[K1] + [SB28_60_Cx]","K1 = 4 ms +","SB28 = 0 ms","null"
"K1 + KS28","[K1] + [KS28_60]","K1 = 0.5 ms +","KS28 = O ms","null"
"K1 + KS28","[K1] + [KS28_60_C]","K1 = 6 ms +","KS28 = 0 ms","null"
"K1 + KS28","[K1] + [KS28_60_Cx]","K1 = 4 ms +","KS28 = 0 ms","null"
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends on how you define an "item". From the structure you shared, I guess it is one element from the `table_row_sections` array:

```json
[
 {
   table_header: {},
   table_row_sections: [
     item1,
     item2,
     ...
   ]
 },
 {
   table_header: {},
   table_row_sections: [
     item1,
     item2,
     ...
   ]
 }
]
```

The `JsonItemReader` provided by Spring Batch expects the input to be an array of items (mentioned in the javadoc), something like this:

```
[
 jsonObject1,
 jsonObject2,
 ...
]
```

So if you want to use that reader, you need to prepare the input to the expected format (this can be done in a preparatory step). Otherwise, you would need to create a custom reader that targets nested elements.

Comment: Hey Mahmoud, thanks so much for your answer. What I don't understand is how it will ever be possible to reformat the data with Spring Batch as you have suggested. The reformating step will necessarily produce more items than it takes in. How is that possible?

Comment: The reader provided by Spring Batch isn't suitable for your custom requirement, you need a custom reader. Another option, which would be easier to implement (compared to a custom reader with all the details of parsing json content), is to prepare the input in a preparatory step with a `SystemCommandTasklet` that invokes `jq` (or something similar depending on the platfron which you deploy your job).